# How to calculate true height of html element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html element whose `height` is set to `100vh` and value of `overflow` is set to `auto`. So user can scroll the element to view it. What I want is to calculate actual height of the element. I am using `offsetHeight` property to calculate height. But is is giving me only `100vh` height. But what I want is the height which will be given by `offsetHeight` when `height` of element is set to `auto`. How to calculate it when `height` of the element is set to `100vh`.

Comment: You look for [element.scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)...

Comment: if its 100vh, then you can get the value from `window.innerHeight`, btw 100vh won't be correct in i(phone|pad), so is better to set a var and use css `var(--vh)` instead, example: https://repl.it/@lcherone/iPad-100vh-fix#index.html

Answer (score 0):

I am new in this business but I use this code the calculate height of the div (whatever div that I choose It doesn't matter).

```
let height = document.querySelector("div").offsetHeight;

  if (
    document.body.scrollTop > height  ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop > height
  ) {
    //code
  } else {
   //code
  }
```